# Plotting a parametric function for a given prior distribution of parmaeters

Tags: distributions, parametric-functions, simulation

I have a function $f(x, \alpha, \beta)$. The function is piecewise defined and not analytically integrable. I would like to do the following: draw from a distribution on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, compute $f(x,\alpha, \beta)$ for each draw and take the average to plot graphically a function $\bar{f}(x)$ which depends on $x$ only. Is there any short command on mathematica that does this for me or should I code up the whole thing in the form of a monte carlo simulation?

Comment: Please post the function by Mathematica code and related formula.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please post a minimal example such that forum participants can copy Mathematica code from your post to a notebook with a fresh kernel and replicate the challenges you face. Thanks.